# Journaltitle between double inverted commas

Tags: biblatex

I thought it was much easier but I can't actually find a solution. I just need to put the journaltitle between double inverted commas (“”) instead of the quotation marks I have in my MWE.
Any help?

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}
@article{Ben:Mat,
    Author = {Lise {Bender Jørgensen}},
    Journal = {Antiquité Tardive},
    Pages = {87-99},
    Title = {A Matter of Material: Changes in Textiles from Roman Sites in Egypt's Eastern Desert},
    Volume = {11},
    Year = {2004}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
            firstinits=true,    
            citepages=omit,                 
            backend=biber,  
        ]{biblatex} 

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}  

\addbibresource{archivio.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[88]{Ben:Mat} 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does that mean that you want all quotation marks to be “” or *only* those for the journal title? If all quotation marks should be ", you'd go with `\usepackage[autostyle,italian=quotes]{csquotes}`. But if all others should stay `guillemets` and only the journal title needs to change, we need to dig deeper. Needless to say this is extremely inconsistent.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second. My publisher asks for journaltitle in “”, as inconsistent it can be...

Comment: It would be better to input the author as `author={Bender Jørgensen, Lise}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all other quotation marks should remain as is, you need resort to low-level commands.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\textquotedblleft #1\textquotedblright}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
            giveninits=true,    
            citepages=omit,                 
            backend=biber,  
        ]{biblatex} 

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\textquotedblleft #1\textquotedblright}  

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Hullo}

\cite[380]{sigfridsson} 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]